# Migrate Objective c To swift completionBlock

Tags: ios, swift

Some Body please help me to migrate this following code from objective C to swift2.

```
ccRegistrationVC.completionBlock = ^(BNCCRegCompletion completion, BNAuthorizedCreditCard *card){
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
};
```

Comment: try in this https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/

Comment: Instead of blindly copy and pasting your obj-c code into a Swift converter, I would highly recommend you familiarise yourself with [the Swift closure syntax](http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/) (seeing as it's a pretty important part of the language). The [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) are also pretty extensive on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

full

```
ccRegistrationVC.completionBlock = { (completion: BNCCRegCompletion, card: BNAuthorizedCreditCard) in 
  self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

shorter

```
ccRegistrationVC.completionBlock = { 
  self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

You might need to add some unwraps on the navigationController line